# Javascript linking failed into HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following problems with linking a javascript file into a html5 project

I'm working with 2 js files for the project: one ( and the main js fail ) is in the same folder with html file. The other js file is in another folder.

So I link them both in my html file, but the second js file seems like not working.

I want to mention that if I put the code from the second js file into the first one, the function is working prefectly.

My folder structure:

[FolderStructure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yn6DF.png)

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML5 Puzzle</title>
    <script>
 
    </script>
</head>
 
<body onload="init();">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
 
</html>
```

proiect.js

```js
const PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY = 4;
const PUZZLE_HOVER_TINT = '#009900';
 
var _canvas;
var _stage;
 
var _img;
var _pieces;
var _puzzleWidth;
var _puzzleHeight;
var _pieceWidth;
var _pieceHeight;
var _currentPiece;
var _currentDropPiece;
 
var _mouse;


function init(){
    _img = new Image();
    _img.addEventListener('load',onImage,false);
    _img.src = "mke.jpg";
}
```

xxs.js

```js
const PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY = 4;
const PUZZLE_HOVER_TINT = '#009900';
 
var _canvas;
var _stage;
 
var _img;
var _pieces;
var _puzzleWidth;
var _puzzleHeight;
var _pieceWidth;
var _pieceHeight;
var _currentPiece;
var _currentDropPiece;
 
var _mouse;


function shufflePuzzle(){
    _pieces = shuffleArray(_pieces);
    _stage.clearRect(0,0,_puzzleWidth,_puzzleHeight);
    var i;
    var piece;
    var xPos = 0;
    var yPos = 0;
    for(i = 0;i < _pieces.length;i++){
        piece = _pieces[i];
        piece.xPos = xPos;
        piece.yPos = yPos;
        _stage.drawImage(_img, piece.sx, piece.sy, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight, xPos, yPos, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
        _stage.strokeRect(xPos, yPos, _pieceWidth,_pieceHeight);
        xPos += _pieceWidth;
        if(xPos >= _puzzleWidth){
            xPos = 0;
            yPos += _pieceHeight;
        }
    }
    document.onmousedown = onPuzzleClick;
}
```

Comment: The **lib** isn't in the same directory so maybe try `../lib/xxs.js`

Comment: Please post your actual code, not a screenshot of it.

Comment: @RacilHilan added.

Comment: Do not delete relevant parts of your question only because the problem is solved. These q/a are not just for those asking, but serve as a reference to all programmers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `<script type="text/javascript" src="./proiect.js"></script>`

where `./` means current folder.

No need to `re-declare` the `variables` you already declared. Erase this from the second `.js file` (the `first .js file from the top` in the `HTML document` must keep this declaration):

```
var imagine;
var piese;
var wJoc;
var hJoc;
var wPiesa;
var hPiesa;
var picked;
var dropped;

var mouseXY;
```

Just use them without declaration (in the file that comes last - declare the variables in proiect.js)

Also, `xxs.js` is in the same folder as `index.html` so that would make it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/xxx.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Edward No problem, glad to hear you got it working :) And, use my code for the `two javascript files` it's cleaner and more understandable. Peace

Comment: copied it.ty.  May I ask you to delete The Code now, please? It is for a school Project and im not allowed to get Code from The internet and im afraid it will appear on automatic checking. Not sure how plagism system working

Answer (score 0):

Try flipping the order of your javascript files in the HTML code. The order of includes can matter.

If that doesn't work, post the javascript code for review.